# Filamentgroup date range picker

Tags: daterangepicker

I installed the daterange picker but is not opening the drop down. Firebug was giving me a type error so I added the jQuery noconflict. No more firebug errors display but still does not popup. I  installed the same code on another page and all was fine. Which leads me to believe there must still be some conflict. How can I troubleshoot that?

Non working code (center  of page: Search by Specific dare range)
http://www.vbcover.com/customdev/bodybuilding/member.php?1-Lionel

Exactly same code working on a different page (click to select a date)
http://www.vbcover.com/customdev/bodybuilding/forumdisplay.php?2-Main-Forum

Comment: I installed jQuerify, downloaded latest jQuery, latest daterangepicker, still no luck

Comment: I finally got it by doing jQuery( document ).ready(function( $ ) instead of (function($)